# Advice for running concurrent pysftp commands

Tags: python, django, pysftp

I am requesting advice for running concurrent `pysftp` API commands, such as listing files in a directory and downloading them from a server. It seems that when I test this all requests are blocked until the previous is finished.

I'm using `pysftp` with Django and I'm not sure how to implement this in a way that will scale a bit so I can have multiple users on the page making requests without them being blocked until another users request has been served.

I tried something like this:

```
class sftp:
    def __init__(self):
        self.response = HttpResponse()
        self.cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
        self.cnopts.hostkeys = None
    def download(self):
        with pysftp.Connection('host.exmaple.com', username='user1', password='test_password',
                               cnopts=self.cnopts) as sftp:
            sftp.getfo(
                '/var/lib/stuff/file.mp3',
                self.response)
            self.response['Content-Type'] = 'audio/mp3'
        return self.response
```

Then in my view I would call something like this:

```
return sftp().download()
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed something similar for one of my projects.
I wrote a module that handle listing and reading files on remote server over SSH.
Difference is that it's not using `pysftp` but `paramiko`, but it should do the job I guess.

```
import paramiko


class SSHClient:
    __slots__ = ['transport', 'sftp']

    def __init__(self, host, user, passw, port):
        """Init connection to SFTP server.
        Args:
            host (str): Server IP address
            user (str): Server username
            passw (str): Server password
            port (int): connection port
        """
        self.transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))
        self.transport.connect(username=user, password=passw)
        self.sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(t=self.transport)

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exception_type, exception_value, traceback):
        """Close SFTP connection"""
        self.transport.close()
        self.sftp.close()

    def list_files(self, remote_path) -> list:
        """List files from specific server directory.
        Args:
            remote_path (str): SFTP server path directory.
        Returns:
            list of files & folders in directory.
        """
        return self.sftp.listdir(path=remote_path)

    def read_remote_file(self, remote_path, filename):
        """Read remote file content from server.
        Args:
            remote_path (str): SFTP server path.
            filename (str): name of file.
        """
        return self.sftp.open(
            filename='{path}/{file}'.format(path=remote_path, file=filename),
            mode='r'
        )

    def close_conn(self) -> None:
        """Close SFTP connection"""
        self.transport.close()
        self.sftp.close()
```

Then you could download a file using the content fetched using `read_remote_file()` to one of your views in your `Django` app.